# Dynamic segment in resourceful route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing, link-to

I want to confirm user emails, by sending them a link to click in the email body. I would like it to be something like  `GET /users/23/confirm/1234` . This would confirm user #23 with the verification key 1234.

I tried :

```
resources :users do
    member do
       match '/confirm/:token' => 'users#confirm'
    end
end
```

But I'm unable to set up the link_to method appropriately in my email body. Any suggestions ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can jump on to the console and type

```
$ rake routes
```

This will tell you the named routes for all of your possible routes. This particular route will not be in there as you have not named it. You need the `:as` param

```
match '/confirm/:token' => 'users#confirm', :as => :confirm
```

Then the route will probably be (you can confirm with rake routes):

```
users_confirm_path(user_id, token)
```

Comment: rake routes is very helpful. Setting it up like you wrote gives confirm_users_path(user_id, token). Thanks a lot !

Comment: In Rails 4, you can have the list of routes and respective helper methods if you do like this localhost/<any_string_or_char_not_matching_with_routes> . I am not sure, it displays the routes on lower version of Rails.

FROM http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
You can visit http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes in your browser during DEV environment